# Авторизация между winforms и web api

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

Всем привет. Пишу сейчас систему для работы с бд(mysql). Изначально был написан просто клиент, который сам с базой работал(база на локальном сервере в одной сети с клиентом). У каждого пользователя свой компьютер, то есть с одной машины обычно один логин. С простой авторизацией, которая запоминалась в свойствах приложения с помощью некоторых системных айдишников (айди материнки + учетка, например). Сейчас пишу сервис, для работы с базой, что бы вынести всю логику в него, а в клиенте оставить только связь с сервисом. Подскажите как лучше всего реализовать авторизацию клиент-сервер. Все данные об учетках пользователей хранятся в бд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [token-base авторизацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token). В Identity уже всё реализовано, только правильно настроить остаётся. При авторизации пользователь получил ключ-токен, который будет отправлять в хедере каждого запроса к серверу.